# C Dynamic Allocation w/Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Why do we use pointers and malloc/calloc when we use dynamic sized arrays instead of giving the size of the array as a variable?

```
int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) array[i] = 1;

// What are their differences?

int array[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) array[i] = 1;
```

Comment: Also in C we do not cast the result of `malloc`, because doing so has only drawbacks and no advantage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Why? Where do local variables get allocated? What limits are imposed on the size of those variables? What lifetime to locally allocated variables have?

Comment: One important difference (apart from the fact that one is an array and the other is a pointer) is that the memory allocated by `malloc` needs to be `free`d to avoid a memory leak.